# replace text via database in basic4android

Tags: android, database, replace, basic4android

I wanted to set Label1's text, to Edittext's text, but I wanted to replace some characters though, but the characters were too many and I had to write multiple codes like this:

```
Label1.text = Edittext.text.Replace("A","B")
Label1.text = Edittext.text.Replace("B","C")
Label1.text = Edittext.text.Replace("D","E")
```

and so on...

so I decided put those characters (which I wanted to replace), into a `DATABASE`, so I built database and a column, which one name's was: **Normal**,
and built a second column, which one name's was: **Replaced**, and I wrote the **SQL** and **Cursor** and ... codes for loading the database.
but I have problem, I don't know how to get texts from **Normal Column** and replace them with **Replaced Column**, I used this code but it seems it doesn't work:

```
Label1.Text = Edittext1.Text.Replace(Cur1.GetString("Normal"),Cur1.GetString("Replaced"))
```

I would be very grateful if someone would help me

sorry for bad English

Answer (score 1):

In your code,didn't saved text in EditText1 after editing

You have to save editing string in variable and use it in all code